# Showing The Two Groups $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ are not Isomorphic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have trying to show that $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, but I have a really dumb question which needs to be answered in order to prove this result by contradiction. (Note, I am not going to type up my proof; that'd would take more time than I want to spend). Suppose through some reasoning, we arrive at the statement

> $\frac{xm}{n} = \frac{1}{n+1},$

where $\frac{m}{n}$ is assumed to be the generator of $\mathbb{Q}$. My question is, wouldn't this imply that either $n|(n+1)$ or $(n+1)|n$ , depending upon which of the two fractions above is the reduced form. If so, this is the contradiction I need.

Does this question make sense? In short, does

> $\frac{xm}{n} = \frac{1}{n+1} \implies n|(n+1)$ or $(n+1)|n$ ?

Comment: What is $q{}{}$?

Comment: Whoops! It should be $n$. Allow me to edit the post.

Comment: There are some $q$s left.

Comment: I think I got them all this time.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but $Z$ and $Q$ are not isomorphic, because there is no element $x\in Z$ such that $x+x=1$, but for every element $q\in Q$ you have $q/2+q/2=q$.

Comment: I don't understand why I am receiving downvotes...I think it is a pretty simple question: I have an equation, and I want to know what the equation implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearranging, you have $xm(n+1) = n$, so that $n+1\mid n$ (recall that the definition of divides for $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ is that $a\mid b$ if and only if there exists $c\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ac = b$), which is a contradiction since $n\neq 0$. I'm assuming you've also ruled out the case $n = -1$, as this renders your $1/(n+1)$ meaningless.

Comment: I hadn't ruled out the $n=-1$ case, but it shouldn't be difficult to deal with. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @user193319 you can actually circumvent it by making the assumption that $n > 0$ without loss of generality by pulling the negative into the $m$ if $m/n < 0$, but it's important to be aware of the potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an integer, then this implies $n+1|n$.

If $x$ is not an integer, we can't draw any conclusions really.

Here I'm assuming $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, since you said $\frac{m}{n}$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Q}$.